# How do I call a function only when a React property changes?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react, meteor-tracker

I wish to show a modal dialog box (such as an `alert()`) every time a Meteor subscription, tracked in React with `withTracker`, changes.

I have tried using `Tracker.autorun` to track changes but cannot work out where in the code to place it. It does not seem to work in the `Component` constructor and runs every time if placed in `render()`.

This is an outline of what my code looks like:

```
class Foo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Example Header</h1>
            { this.maybeShowAlert() }
        );
    }

    maybeShowAlert() {
       // ONLY if bar has been updated
       alert('bar has changed');
    }
}

export default withTracker(() => {

    Meteor.subscribe('bar')

    return {
        bar: Bar.findOne({})
    };
})(Foo);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't used Meteor before, but if you want to do things in response to state/prop changes then `componentDidUpdate()` is the lifecycle method for it. E.g.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.bar !== prevProps.bar) {
        // bar prop has changed
        alert("bar changed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use `Tracker.autorun`, then the best place to call that is in `componentDidMount`, because it's called only once after the component has been [mounted](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). You only need to call the tracker function once since the tracker function will rerun whenever the reactive data sources that it depends on ever [changes](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun). In the tracker function is where you will call `maybeShowAlert` depending on the value of `bar` like so,

```
componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        let bar = this.props.bar;
        if (bar) {
            this.maybeShowAlert();
        }
    }
}
```